# HTML circle div with image trying to get hovering text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a square div that says "read more" when hovering over a circle div with a picture inside it. Been trying different things and haven't found a working solution on google.

HTML

```
        <div class = "portfolio" id = "first"> <!-- makes the circle -->
            <a href = "cake-page.html"> 
                <div class = "readm"> Read more </a> </div>
                <img src = "cake.jpg" /> 
                    <p> The cake </p> </div>
```

CSS

```
.portfolio {
    /* the circles on the portfolio-page */
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 2px solid purple;
}



.portfolio.img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s ease;
    background-size: 90px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
   -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.portfolio:hover {
     /* hover effect on portfolio circles */
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: 1 ease; 
    visibility: visible;
}
```

So either the text pushed the image down or it stays in the top of the circle and I can't get it to hover together with the other hover effect. I want the "read more" to pop-up in a rectangular div when hovering over together with the other hover effect.
I did not include the div class "readm" since I can't get it to work. FYI I'm pretty new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little tough without a working example and it'd be good to see the readm css since we need to see what isn't working. That said, have you tried something like this:

```
.readm {
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.portfolio:hover .readm {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Also I would place the start of that a tag inside the readm div.

Comment: That actually did it. Thanks!

Comment: @Oliver No problem! Glad it worked. I've done things similar to this before. If this answer fixed your problem would you mind marking it as correct?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Just one slightly different question. If I would like to change the opacitiy of the hovering text, how would I do? Since the "main" hovering is inside of the circle div it also "decides" over the text hovering inside the div? Do you understand what I mean? Can you do anything about that? I've tried but can only make it to opacity: 0.6; since that is what the portfolio:hover has.

Comment: Hmm, again it's a little tough without a working example. From what I gather you want the image to gain an opacity of .6 right? Well since the image and the p tag are siblings you can affect their opacities differently. Maybe instead of .portfolio losing opacity it can be ".portfolio:hover img {opacity: .6;}" The only thing here is then the borders of portfolio won't lose opacity, but you can actually set an rgba value for a border, like (255, 255, 255, .6) that would work in this situation. Just a thought. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fix your markup. 
You are closing the anchor ("a") tag before closing a DIV. That alone will make your CSS fail.
I presume you want to close the DIV like so:

```
<div class="readm"><a href="cake-page.html">Read more</a></div>
```